# How to pass state in useNavigate to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, jsx

**The main code is this:**

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
    const gotToNext = () => {
            let formDef = {
                formCategoryCd: formCatCode,
                formTypeCd: formTypeCode,
                headerTitle: HeaderTitle,
                footerTitle: FooterTitle,
                verticalSectionNumber: vSecNumber,
                horizSectionNumber: hSecNumber,
                formDefName: FormDefName,
                tabNumber: 6,
                formFont: 10,
                formFontSize: 5.2,
            }
            FormServices.AddFormDef(formDef).then((res) => {
                setformDefData(res.data)
                navigate({ pathname: "/vertical_section", state:{formdef_data: res.data}});
            })
        }
```

**The other component where I want to receive this state:**

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
    // setdefLockData(location.state.formdef_data)
    console.log("data",location.state)
  }, []);
```

**but I get null state there. Please guide what am I doing wrong here.**

Comment: What are you trying to specifically pass? `formdef_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```js
navigate({ pathname: "/vertical_section", state:{formdef_data: res.data}});
```

Try this instead:

```js
navigate("/vertical_section", { state: { formdef_data: res.data } });
```

The state object should be passed as the second argument to the navigate function.